# Binding ko computed in ui

Tags: knockout.js

Please help. I have a computed observable itemsOnCurrentPage that is binded to a tbody. the computed observable is updated using a search function. but my ui still displays the same data. it does not show the updated content of the itemsOnCurrentPage.

```
 var listofcases = ko.observableArray();

    var itemsOnCurrentPage = ko.computed(function () {
        var startIndex = pageSize * currentPageIndex();
        console.log(listofcases.slice(startIndex, startIndex + pageSize));
        return listofcases.slice(startIndex, startIndex + pageSize);
    }, this);

    function SearchCases(username, role, st, ed, ss) {

        $.getJSON('/breeze/Workflow/ListOfCases?UserId=' + username +
                                                '&Role=' + role +
                                                '&RouteId=Annotate&_st=' + st +
                                                '&_ed=' + ed +
                                                '&_ss=' + ss,
                  function (cases) {
                      if (cases.length != 0) {
                          $.each(cases, function (index, _case) {
                              listofcases.push(new CaseDataViewModel(_case));
                          });
                          itemsOnCurrentPage(listofcases());

                      }
                      else {
                          console.log("dddd");
                          listofcases.push(new CaseDataViewModel(_case));
                      }
                  });
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to include the HTML that contains the bindings.

Answer (score 2):

You should not call computed from `SearchCases` function. Knockout automatically recalculates computed when `listofcases` is updated. 
Remove the following line:

```
itemsOnCurrentPage(listofcases());
```

Answer (score 0):

As Artem said, you should not set the computed anywhere. Remove this line:

```
itemsOnCurrentPage(listofcases());
```

You also don't need to modify the computed, so passing this to the computed is not required, and I suspect that this might be causing the issue. Try replacing your computed with this:

```
var itemsOnCurrentPage = ko.computed(function () {
        var startIndex = pageSize * currentPageIndex();
        console.log(listofcases().slice(startIndex, startIndex + pageSize));
        return listofcases().slice(startIndex, startIndex + pageSize);
    });
```